# How do I show ads on Trilogy and Stack Exchange sites with AdBlock enabled?

Tags: support, advertising

I would like to see advertising on Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User, and all Stack Exchange sites, however I have AdBlock installed.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the following exception rules to AdBlock preferences:

- @@||askubuntu.com^$document
- @@||mathoverflow.net^$document
- @@||serverfault.com^$document
- @@||stackapps.com^$document
- @@||stackexchange.com^$document
- @@||stackoverflow.com^$document
- @@||superuser.com^$document