# Image of Stack Exchange button is blocked by Adblock

Tags: support, design, top-bar

Chrome and IE 11 are fine, I'm only able to reproduce this in Firefox. Using version 27.0.1 on Windows 7. Meta as well as all the other sites are affected.

> [image: top bar screenshot]

I can still see the hover effect, but the image is gone. I see this in Firebug:

> [image: firebug screenshot]

The image doesn't show up in the Network tab. I am able to see the image by visiting https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/stackoverflowmeta/../img/share-sprite-new.png?v=204b1e0e421b which goes to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/img/share-sprite-new.png?v=204b1e0e421b

I've done Ctrl-F5, I've cleared the cache and I've tried Private Browsing. Possibly related to [Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ image wacked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225821/stack-exchange-multicollider-superdropdown-image-wacked) ?

Comment: no repro for me

Comment: @Jehof Well that sucks :\

Comment: I have posted a message in the Easylist Forum, section [Report incorrectly removed content](http://forums.lanik.us/viewforum.php?f=64&sid=2d21a062f154cc6f31426b26213116a9), but as I am not registered there, a moderator has to check it before it is readable for all.

Comment: Update – see on Easylist Forum: [StackExchange network](http://forums.lanik.us/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=16078&sid=78f168523761ba407c3efae800f668f6).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the filter lists that ABP installs by default (Fanboy Social) blocks all images whose filename starts with "share-sprite-", and the sprite file that contains the button's logo has such a file name.

It looks like someone responsible has already noticed the problem, because the current version of the list (I just installed ABP to test this) already contains an exception for that file, however only for stackoverflow.com. So on SO you get the image, on the rest of the SE sites you don't.

Therefore I suggest you contact them to whitelist it everywhere, or add the exception yourself.

Comment: I tried posting [here](http://forums.lanik.us/posting.php?mode=post&f=64) but my IP is blacklisted for some reason. If anyone else wants to try it, [this](http://pastebin.com/Tc2JNDLL) is the message I was going to post. Anyway, I've already disabled APB on the SE network now.

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem in Chrome 33. After some quick checks, it appears like my adblocker is the cause. After disabling my adblocker, the image appeared again.

Looking further into the Adblock blocks, it appears like cdn.sstatic.net is seen as an external party. It is not SE's fault, it's adblocks fault.

Comment: I had just found that out myself, disabling Adblock fixes it indeed. Still weird that it's also blocked on Meta, because Meta doesn't use the CDN.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Adblock Plus is blocking the image. I'll disable it for SE then.

Exception rules to allow ads on the SE network can be found here: [How do I show ads on Trilogy and Stack Exchange sites with AdBlock enabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90230/how-do-i-show-ads-on-trilogy-and-stack-exchange-sites-with-adblock-enabled/)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my FF 27.0.1 browser and I removed one of the filter subscriptions from Adblock - Fanboy's Social Blocking List - and problem is resolved.