# Top Left menus are missing

Tags: support, header, menu-bar

When I got on today, the top left header menus were gone.  The places they should be seem to still be functional, but it looks like just a black bar.  Browser is Firefox 27, OS is Windows 7.

[image: meta.SO]

Here is a screenshot of main SO

[image: main.SO]

Just so we are clear, this is only the 3 menus in the top left.  The user image and badges are still fine.

[image]

When new activity happens, it puts up the red background with the number in it.

[image]

Comment: What browser / OS?

Comment: Are you [using AdBlock](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225831/image-of-stack-exchange-button-is-blocked-by-adblock)?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Indeed I am.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Ad-Block was blocking the sprite sheet.   Adding an exception on `/img/share-sprite-new.png` allows it to load for all SE sites (only tested on 4).

To add an exception, use hotkey `CTRL+SHIFT+V`.  Then right-click on the `share-sprite-new.png` and click "Add exception rule".  Select "Custom" and in the textbox enter `/img/share-sprite-new.png`

Comment: As you have >200 rep on most of your accounts you probably don't need  adblock at all (not that the ads on stack exchange are very in your face and do pay for...well everything)

Comment: They got pretty flexible definition for "Ad". CSS sprites can hardly be used as advertisement. Oh well, those who use it should know it might block about anything, rendering all websites blank.