# Stackoverflow not showing notifications and rep changes in chrome

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, design, google-chrome

I'd like to know why is stackoverflow not showing proper styles on chrome and how to fix it. This started happening yesterday. I'm using Chrome: Version 33.0.1750.154 m: Windows 7 x64.

Chrome:

[image: SO Appearance in chrome]

But on IE it appears fine:

[image: SO Appearance in IE]

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Adblock?

Comment: No repro on Chrome 33.0.1750.154 / Win7/x64

Comment: @hims056 Yes I'm using AdBlock and disabling it helped thanks. But what's weird is that I've been using AdBlock all along and everything was appearing fine. Do you perhaps know why? Has there been an update to AdBlock or something?

Comment: AdBlockPlus seems to be the issue. Enabling AdBlock alone works fine.

Comment: FWIW: See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90230/187824).

Comment: SO should take the code suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8626373/447356) and show something to those poor souls.

Comment: FYI works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added these filters to my AdBlock Plus extention so that it may not block ads from the StackExchange related sites. Taken from [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90231/255771)

```
@@||askubuntu.com^$document
@@||mathoverflow.net^$document
@@||serverfault.com^$document
@@||stackapps.com^$document
@@||stackexchange.com^$document
@@||stackoverflow.com^$document
@@||superuser.com^$document
```

Now everything works fine with my extentions enabled.